# javascript: how to exit a loop by clicking a button

Tags: javascript

I did some searching and I'm not even sure if what I want to do is good javascript practice.
I have a while loop that I would like to exit from early if a stop button is clicked.

```
$( "#go" ).click(function() {
  var gotime = 1;
  while (gotime < 100) {
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      var divName = "floatName" + i;
      console.log(divName);
      $( "#" + divName ).animate({
        left: Math.random()*500 + "px",
        top: Math.random()*500 + "px"
      }, 500, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    };

    gotime += 1;

    $( "stop" ).click(function() {
      gotime = 101;
    });
    };
});
```

This doesn't work though. I originally had an endless loop (not incrementing gotime).

http://jsfiddle.net/cvoxe465/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `setInterval`:

Js:

```
var interval;
$("#go").click(function () {
    var gotime = 1;
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            var divName = "floatName" + i;
            console.log(divName);
            $("#" + divName).css({
                left: Math.random() * 500 + "px",
                top: Math.random() * 500 + "px"
            });
        };
        gotime += 1;
        if (gotime > 100) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 500)
});
$("#stop").on('click', function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

css:

```
#randomFloat {
    color: red;
}
#floatName1, #floatName0 {
    transition : 0.5s left, 0.5s top;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AjayMathur/w6whzqao/2/)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I guess it loops through the for very fast. I was thinking it looped through every 500ms, which was the animation time.

Comment: @DougSmith : HI, The reason why i posted this answer here is because you asked for good javascript practice. If you make variable `gotime = 101`, when user clicks on stop then you can never resume animation. If you remove it then even if you stop the animation the while loop will run 100 times. Now read the answers again and see which is better one. :)

Comment: @AJ:  yes, and I can also put the transition into #randomFloat because I see that it gets inherited. Thanks!

Comment: @AJ  I'm coming back to this and doing some debugging.  This strategy works well but there is a problem is the user clicks #go and then clicks #go again.  The animation will not stop after doing this. I forked [the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shmish/qm7kvc64/) to try and use the `gotime` to toggle the `clearInterval` but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it stops if you wait for some time. The problem is you execute animation very often and `$.animate` have to queue it. There is [$.stop](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) method that allow you to stop the currently-running animation. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L7bftnre/9/)

```
$( "#stop" ).click(function() {
  gotime = 101;
  $('#floatName0, #floatName1').stop(true, true);
});
```

**EDIT:**

Note that in the code that you provided there is mistake. Instead `$("stop")` you need to use `$("#stop")`.

Comment: Please also mention that `$(stop)` should have been `$(#stop)`, that was the reason why the click button event was not firing and eventually we had to wait for the loop to finish.

Answer (score 1):

`animate` doesn't block the loop. The animations are stacked up and then executed, but the loop finishes a lot earlier. Here is something that works:

```
var loopAllowed = false;
$('#go').click(function(){
    loopAllowed = true;
    var max = 2;
    var loop = function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < max; i++){
            var divName = "floatName" + i;
            $( "#" + divName ).animate({
                left: Math.random()*500 + "px",
                top: Math.random()*500 + "px"
            }, 500, i === max - 1 && loopAllowed ? loop : undefined);
        }
    };
    loop();
});

$('#stop').click(function(){
    loopAllowed = false;    
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yonngp71/1/). We manually call the `loop` function **after** the animation has ended (by passing it as the callback function). If `loopAllowed` is false (e.g. set to false by clicking `#stop`), then it won't be passed as the callback function and the looping stops.

Comment: I like this solution because I plan on animating several more names, and this solution doesn't require more calls to floatNameX

Comment: Could you briefly explain what the i == max - 1 && loopAllowed ? loop : undefined does? I understand that the i == max - 1 && loopAllowed checks for a condition, but I don't get the ? loop : undefined.  As well, I don't see how these parts fit in with the documentation for jquery's docs http://api.jquery.com/animate/.  Is it part of the queue option?

Comment: @DougSmith [It's the ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It's essentially a shorthand for `if` - if the condition is `true`, pass `loop` as callback, if it is `false`, pass `undefined` as callback (which will end the loop). The callback is called **after** the animation is finished - which is why we can loop like this (after the animation, `loop` is called *again*). The `queue` option is `true` by default (the animations are placed in a queue by default and then executed sequentially), but my code doesn't touch that.